# Running bash script with parameter

Tags: bash

I've got problem with my script. I have to run script with parameter. For example:

```
./birhday 10 2000
```

and i should get this:

```
"at 10 2000 was born Mark,Jordan"
```

The names have to be loaded from the list, for example:

ListOfNames:

```
2000
01 Jane,Marry
02 Jason,Ted
.
.
.
12 Stephen,Victor
```

And i have no clue how to do that. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I would change the format of your data to this:

```
2000-01 Jane,Marry
2000-02 Jason,Ted
.
.
.
2000-12 Stephen,Victor
```

It would really simplify the script. In this case it will be as simple as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  echo "Usage format: $(basename $0) MM YYYY"
  exit 1
else
  NAMES=$(grep $2-$1 ListOfNames | awk '{print $2}')
  echo "at $1 $2 was born $NAMES"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too

```
seen=$(sed -n '/'"$2"'/{:A;n;/'"$1"'/!bA;s/^[^ ]* //;p;q}' ListOfNames)
[ -n "$seen" ] && echo "at $1 $2 was born $seen"
```